# How to concat a number type in a select sql in Mybatis?

Tags: mysql, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I want to select  a result according to the search number parameter,for example, if I pass  `7`, I want the sql statement like `select * from student where DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= date(CREATETIME)`,Now in Mybatis,I try to write like this,and also change `${pd.intervalDay}` to `#{pd.intervalDay}`,but it is wrong.How to change it?

```
<!-- pd is hasmap type -->
<select id="selectstudentresult" parameterType="page" resultType="pd">
 select * from student 
  <where>      
   <if test="pd.intervalDay!=null">
    and  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL ${pd.intervalDay} DAY) <= date(a.UPDATETIME)
    </if>
 </where>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selectstudentresult" parameterType="page" resultType="pd">
 select * from student 
  <where>      
   <if test="intervalDay!=null">
    and  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL #{intervalDay} DAY) <= date(a.UPDATETIME)
    </if>
 </where>
```

Use above code,since you are sending parameter as **page**(pojo class),you can access the variable directly..and no need to add `pd.intervalday` thats not a parameter-that is result type.